# What is the meaning of the following code

Tags: c#

Please describe the following code.

```
dr[0] = "CC-123";
dr[0].ToString().Replace("AA","BB")
```

Comment: If this is a homework/test question please don't post it on SO. If this is part of something you're working on then please explain what code it's in, what you're trying to do and what the issue is.

Comment: i am not expert in C# or IT only i want to meaning

Comment: The meaning is pretty much the same as you would read it, convert a string to a string and then dont replace anything. You should explain what part of the code you don't understand and what why what you researched didnt help

Comment: But where did you find this line of code? Stack Overflow is for people looking for answers to problems they've attempted to solve but cannot find a solution. It's not a teaching website to explain how functions work.

Answer (score 1):

> Please describe the following code.

The only thing that actually has any effect is the first line. The second line does nothing for two reasons:

- The text does not contain "AA"
- `Replace` is a pure function meaning it does not mutate the object it is invoked on (strings are generally considered immutable).

So it assigns a string value of `"CC-123"` to `dr[0]` and then proceeds to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
dr[0] = "CC-123";
```

The first line assigns the string `CC-123` to the `0` element/index of some structure, `dr`. As `dr` is a meaningless name and no further context is provided, it's impossible to know its datatype or purpose.

```
dr[0].ToString().Replace("AA","BB")
```

The second line of code requests the value stored in `0` element/index of some structure, `dr`, converts it to a string (a likely pointless exercise as it's likely [though not guaranteed] already a string). Finally that string is passed to a likely pointless (though again not guaranteed as the type of `dr` is unknown) call to `Replace()`, which creates a new string, with all occurrences of `AA` changed to `BB`. This new string is then discarded.